# How to build a multi project template in visual studio 2010 with references

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to build a visual studio template that contains 4 solution folders that has multiple project in each folder and some of the projects has references between them.
I got to do this template:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
<TemplateData>
    <Name>My Template</Name>
    <Description>My multi-project template</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>MyTemplate</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>logo.jpg</Icon>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
<ProjectCollection>
    <SolutionFolder Name="Common">
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Common">ProjectName.Common\CommonTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
    </SolutionFolder>
    <SolutionFolder Name="Server">
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.BL">Server\BLTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.DAL">Server\DALTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.DB">Server\DBTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.External">Server\ExternalTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Implementation">Server\ImplementationTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Interface">Server\InterfaceTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
    </SolutionFolder>
    <SolutionFolder Name="Service">
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Service">Service\ServiceTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
    </SolutionFolder>
    <SolutionFolder Name="UI">
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.App">UI\AppTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.ServiceAgent">UI\MyTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
    </SolutionFolder>
</ProjectCollection>
```

But when I'm trying to create a new project with this template I get only 4 empty folders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this blog with explanation and example here:

[Creating an F# Solution Template for Visual Studio 2010](http://bloggemdano.blogspot.co.il/2010/05/creating-f-solution-template-for-visual.html)

The blog's title is misleading, it is actually a good explanation for creating any template.

Hope this is what you've looking for..